# Deleting node without deleting root node

Tags: c#, .net, xml, linq

This is my xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Videos>
    <Playlist>
    </Playlist>
</Videos>
```

xml i want :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Videos>
</Videos>
```

I tried something like :

```
List<XNode> t = xmlDoc.Element("Videos").DescendantNodes().ToList();
  foreach (XNode a in t)
   {
     if (((System.Xml.Linq.XElement)a).Value == "")
                a.Remove();
  }
```

But i get this result :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Videos />
```

Can somebody help ? :/

Comment: Please see ["Should questions include “tags” in their titles?"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles), where the consensus is "no, they should not"!

Comment: ok sorry ! Thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<Videos>
</Videos>
```

and

```
<Videos />
```

is the same thing. So, Where is the problem ?

Comment: Im not familiar with xml si i didn't know that... thanks for the reply !